# Why am I protecting files when I use my back focus button?

Tags: nikon-d5100

I just learned how to use my back focus button on my Nikon D5100.   I have been accidently causing about ten percent of my photofiles to be protected.  I cannot delete them in camera.  I do not know how I am doing this.  I must be pushing the wrong button or something.  What mistake am I making?

Comment: Just a note, if you want to be sure to erase all images, you can format the memory card from within the camera. deletes everything from the card including protected images

Answer (score 3):

I have a D3200, but I suspect they work the same with this. That button does double duty, both as back-button focus (in shooting mode) and as image protection (in reviewing mode). When the camera displays the image you just took, it goes into reviewing mode, so pressing the lock button will protect the image instead of focusing. Two possible solutions:

- Disable Image review. The setting is in different places on different cameras;  according to [KenRockwell.com](http://kenrockwell.com/nikon/d5100/users-guide/controls.htm) (about halfway down the page, with the explanation of the Play button), this is under MENU > PLAY > Image review on the D5100. With image review disabled, you'll stay in shooting mode, so the button will focus instead of protecting the image you just took.
- Push the shutter release down halfway before focusing. This will turn off the image review and go back to shooting mode.

I personally prefer (and use) the first method, since it allows me to shoot faster and (potentially) saves battery life (since the LCD doesn't come on with every shot). Either one should work, though.

Comment: Not directly relevant to the question, but on the D3200 the Image review setting is at MENU > PLAYBACK MENU > Image reveiew.